# What happens if the hostname of a domain goes down?

Tags: networking, hostname

The definition of a hostname according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) is:

> “A LABEL that is assigned to a device connected to a computer network and that is used to identify the device.”

And I've been told that for this fully qualified domain name (FQDN): `en.wikipedia.org`, the `en` part is a hostname.

Does this mean that if I make a website called `www.example.com`, there is a singular device inside the domain `example.com` which has the hostname called `www`? And does this mean that if this singular device with the label `www` goes offline or whatever reason, all my users would not be able to reach `www.example.com`?

Answer (score 1):

> “Does this mean that if I make a website called `www.mywebsite.com`, there is a singular device inside the domain `example.com` which has the hostname called `www`? And does this mean that if this singular device with the label `www` goes offline or whatever reason, all my users would not be able to reach `www.example.com`?”

Yes. That is correct.

I think part of your confusion is you are mixing up domain/hostname info with the actual destination IP addresses connected to that.

All DNS entries like `example.com` and `www` are are alias that point to IP addresses. How you assign those IP addresses and where they go to is up to you.

So you can have a structure like this:

- `www.example.com`: Points to one IP address like `1.2.3.4`.
- `example.com`: Points to another IP address like `5.6.7.8`.

That means that each domain name is a different server, device, etc…

But in many cases for simple websites the architecture is like this:

- `www.example.com`: Points to one IP address like `1.2.3.4`.
- `example.com`: Points to also points to `1.2.3.4`.

The way this works is you can configure your Webservers — typically something like Apache — to respond to both hostnames. So `www.example.com` and `example.com` serves the same exact website.

But Apache can also be configured to handle virtual host configurations. So the one server at `1.2.3.4` can serve two different websites to `www.example.com` and `example.com`.

So this is all about conventions and use of DNS language. The reality is a place like Google doesn’t just have one IP address and one server for all their services. So if `mail.google.com` goes down, the main `google.com` is never affected.

Just always remember that hostnames, domains and subdomains are not codependent to whatever their destination IP address is *unless* you intentionally architect a system like that.

In my example of `www.example.com` and `example.com` both pointing to `1.2.3.4` many basic websites work like that purely to give the end user the convenience of getting the same content at both domain names.

Comment: Then if the hostname/subdomain `www.example.com` points to `1.2.3.4` which is a SINGULAR device, doesn't that mean `example.com` which also points to `1.2.3.4` be referring to a SINGULAR device as well? And by extension, doesn't this mean that `example.com` is not a domain, as the definition of a domain is a network of computers?
Additionally, wouldn't this make `example.com` also be considered a hostname as it refers to a SINGULAR device?

Comment: @user8380672 You are massively overthinking what a physical device is in the context of the language used for domain names. You are simply mixing up what a device is from the language used to describe DNS entries.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that if I make a website called [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com), there is a singular device inside the domain mywebsite.com which has the hostname called www?

Sort of: The [Domain Name Systems (DNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) resolution relies on servers, which are usually responsible for quite a few names. For example, a big corporation `somecorp.com` would then have one server to resolve `someservice.somecorp.com`, `anotherservice.somecorp.com` and so on. Often these systems are also reachable by a name under this domain, like `dns.somecorp.com`. Nearly always there are several servers for redundancy, so you'd get `dns1.somecorpt.com`, `dns2.somecorp.com` etc.

For your website, there's usually one big group of DNS server of your hosting provider that will not only resolve `yourwebsite.com`, but also `hiswebsite.com` and `herwebsite.com`, and that won't be reachable by `*.yourwebsite.com`.

> And does this mean that if this singular device with the label www goes offline or whatever reason,

That's why you have redundant groups of DNS servers: If one goes down, the others still work.

You know, people have given these problems some though over the years ...

Comment: While this is a decent answer, you might want to look at the original poster’s — now closed — [question here](https://superuser.com/q/1603842/167207).

Answer (score 0):

### This is not really how it works.

Internet works with IP addresses. Your router comes preconfigured with the IP address of a DNS server. This DNS server is interrogated to resolve domain names (`example.com`) into an IP address. It doesn't make a difference if it is `www.example.com` or `example.com`.

It just stands as 2 different entries on a DNS server somewhere which responds to requests to resolve those domain names. The entities responsible to register domains are registrars which are accredited by ICANN (https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/register-domain-name-2017-06-20-en). If this server goes down there are copies of it.